# Excel Data Validation AND OR with Range

Tags: excel-formula

```
=IF(OR(AND(A11="3061 - Mexico"),AND(A11="3062 - Brazil")), "Mandatory","Optional")
```

is already working, however, if I put it in range

```
=IF(OR(AND(**A11:A199**="3061 - Mexico"),AND(**A11:A199**="3062 - Brazil")), "Mandatory","Optional")
```

Comment: For the logical ***A11:A199="3061 - Mexico"***, do you want to test if ALL cells have the value, or if ANY cell has the value **??**

Comment: Some sample data and expected outcome will help.

Comment: Hi Gary's Student... yes, I want to test all cells (A11:A199), however, Data Validation cell is only 1,at G2 only.

Comment: @ScottCraner Hi Scott. What I'm doing here is Data Validation. Column in A, when input is 3061 - Mexico or 3062 - Brazil, I am getting Mandatory, which is desired output. For other inputs, I get Optional. That is working fine with A11 as input cell. However, when I make it A11:A199 I am getting #VALUE! error.

Comment: Take your first formula, the one that works,  put it in the column at row 11.  Then drag/copy the cell down to row 199.  The row in the formula will update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Please, give more information to us.

I'm putting this like anwser because is too large to put in comments. But this will be a anwser if you want to know if any cell has the values:

Try something like this:

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(VLOOKUP("3061 - Mexico"; A11:A199;1;FALSE);"") <> "3061 - Mexico";IFERROR(VLOOKUP("3062 - Brazil"; A11:A199;1;FALSE);"") <> "3062 - Brazil");"Optional";"Mandatory")
```

If you want to know if all cells have the value you will need to do the same, but put the others possibles values inside the IF, and use OR instead the AND function (We can think a little bit more if that is the case).